# jquery - change width & height of iframe via button

Tags: jquery, if-statement, iframe, resize, click

I've been trying to mimic the cinema mode functionality of youtube videos for embedded iframes. The idea is to decrease space embedded videos take up in a blog post, but still offer readers the possibility to enlarge the video without having to go fullscreen.

The way it's supposed to work is with a button that is displayed alongside the video. Clicking on it enlarges the video to a certain size, clicking it again downsizes it.

I think I got the functionality down, but it's not working properly, and I can't figure out why. You'll see my code isn't the most efficient, but it still should work. Well, it doesn't.

If you want, use this jfiddle (`https://jsfiddle.net/rjroy8eo/7/`) or find the code below:

HTML:

```
<iframe width="425" height="239" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<button type="button" class="video big">Enlarge</button>
<button type="button" class="video small">Downsize</button>
```

CSS

```
.video {
  margin: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
  width: 90px;
  border: 0px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  float: left;
}

.small {
   display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(".video").click(function() {

  var n = $("iframe").width;

  if (n < 500) {
    $("iframe").width(850).height(478);
    $(".big").toggle();
    $(".small").toggle();
  } else {
    $("iframe").width(425).height(239);
    $(".small").toggle();
    $(".big").toggle();
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I feel dumb. The variable was missing parentheses. [https://jsfiddle.net/rjroy8eo/8/]

```
var n = $("iframe").width();
```